# eslint issue w/react July 2023

Tags: reactjs, compiler-errors, eslint, node-modules, conflict

Anyone else having issues compiling with react npm start and eslint?

exact error:

```
[eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » M:\projects\mern\carousel\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » M:\Projects\MERN\carousel\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".
ERROR in [eslint] Plugin "react" was conflicted between "package.json » eslint-config-react-app » M:\projects\mern\carousel\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js" and "BaseConfig » M:\Projects\MERN\carousel\node_modules\eslint-config-react-app\base.js".

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I tried saving via package.json and it fixed the issue temporarily. But every edit made in .js or .jsx files leads to the compile error again.

I was able to fix it by moving my entire project to my M: drive instead of having it in a directory path with multiple cases such as "M:\Projects\MERN\project-name" .

I found this idea via Geeks for Geeks suggesting:
"Solution 1:  First of all, make sure your naming conventions are right, (Try using lowercase most of the time). "

I've been mostly coding with React + Vite lately and didn't realize coding in React without vite had this issue. :/

I've updated node, react, eslint, cleared cache, etc. Does anyone know a solution without having to change the paths to a direct route with common cased directories or should I change my paths to be more concise? I'm still a bit of a newbie coder and this is my first post on Stack Overflow.

Also - I'm using VSCode as my editor and running on Windows 10.